# Inject viewmodel to widget in hilt dependency injection in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, dagger-hilt

I created a jetpack compose app using hilt dependency Injection. I created a widget using glance and it works successfully. Now I want to create a viewmodel to it and inject using the same mechanism or different mechanism. I tested in different ways. But I didn't get a solution.

I used jetpack compose navigation to navigate through views and I just used one activity only for the main app.

Here is my code relevant to glance widget. If you want more details leave a comment. I shared relevant data.

```
class CustomGlanceWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = MyAppWidget()
}
//@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidget(){
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent { 
            MyContent()
        }
    }

}
@Composable
private fun MyContent(
    //viewModel: BaseEntryWidgetViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, label = {
                Text(text = "Title")
            })
            TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, label = {
                Text(text = "Amount")
            })
            Button(
                text = "Save",
                onClick = { }
            )
            Button(
                text = "Work",
                onClick = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
@HiltViewModel
class BaseEntryWidgetViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val wallletRepositoryService: WalletRepositoryService
):ViewModel(){
    //
}
```

I created a jetpack compose app using hilt dependency Injection. I created a widget using glance and it works successfully. Now I want to create a viewmodel to it and inject using the same mechanism or different mechanism. I tested in different ways. But I didn't get a solution.

I used jetpack compose navigation to navigate through views and I just used one activity only for the main app.

Here is my code relevant to glance widget. If you want more details leave a comment. I shared relevant data.

```
class CustomGlanceWidgetReceiver : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = MyAppWidget()
}
//@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidget(){
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent { 
            MyContent()
        }
    }

}
@Composable
private fun MyContent(
    //viewModel: BaseEntryWidgetViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, label = {
                Text(text = "Title")
            })
            TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, label = {
                Text(text = "Amount")
            })
            Button(
                text = "Save",
                onClick = { }
            )
            Button(
                text = "Work",
                onClick = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
@HiltViewModel
class BaseEntryWidgetViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val wallletRepositoryService: WalletRepositoryService
):ViewModel(){
    //
}
```

Comment: I commented @AndroidEntryPoint and viewmodel injection because those are not works

Comment: Maybe this post can help you? [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76068660/11048731)

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment @AndoridEntryPoint and add these:

You can declare that viewmodel in the body of that function:

```
@Composable
private fun MyContent(){
    viewmodel: BaseEnrtyWidgetViewModel = hiltViewModel()
}
```

And do not forget to add:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application() {
}
```

and also add in you manifest file:

```
android:name=".MyApp"
```

Let me know if it helps you!

Comment: as I see it's impossible to do. because TextField is not  available in glance. that's one of the reason. another reason is after removing those textfiled I couldn't able to run after uncommenting viewmodel and @AndroidEntryPoint. Another errors occured

Comment: @geontricksdeveloper What errors are you getting? Are they build errors or? This should work here is one example, when I used viewmodel with dagger-hilt:

Comment: @geontricksdeveloper:

Composable
fun NewsScreen() {
    val newsViewModel : NewsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val newsResponse = newsViewModel.newsResponse

    LazyColumn {
        items(newsResponse?.newsItems.orEmpty()){newsItem ->
            NewsItemCard(newsItem)
        }
    }
}